# Optimize the code to 0(N) for meeting time problem

Tags: big-o, intervals

Given  a list of meeting start time and end time of people's schedules, find the number of people in given time. The time would be given as integers. For example:

Input is

```
[ [ 12, 14] ,[12,15],[14,16],[13,15]]
```

Output should return

```
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,3,1]
```

How to do in linear time?

I can do it in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Show us how you do it in `O(n^2)`, please...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking at only one day, and `N` is the number of time pairs (which at most include 24 hours in a meeting):

```
output = [0 for i in range(24)] # O(1)

for [start, end] in meetings: # N iterations
    for o in range(end - start + 1): # At most 24 iterations per outer iteration
        output[o + start - 1] += 1
```

At most the inner loop will be performed 24 times for each pair, a constant worst case, and the outer loop will be performed `N` times. So we have worst case `O(24N)`, which is `O(N)`.